# Why does the filtered date range differ from my start date?

Tags: python, dataframe, finance

I use this code to get BTC value but the date is starting previous day which my selected.

INPUT:

```
tickers=['BTC-USD']  # Name of asset
tarih="02-06-2021"
tarih2="05-06-2021"
start=dt.datetime.strptime(tarih, '%d-%m-%Y')
end=dt.datetime.strptime(tarih2, '%d-%m-%Y')
returns=pd.DataFrame()
liste=[]                    

for ticker in tickers:
        data=web.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start,end)
        data=pd.DataFrame(data)
        data[ticker]=data['Adj Close'] #can work with change percentage in order to get more accurate data
        if returns.empty:
            returns=data[[ticker]]
        else:
            returns = returns.join(data[[ticker]],how='outer')#add right column
for dt in daterange(start, end):
    dates=dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    with open("fng_value.txt", "r") as filestream:
            for line in filestream:
                date = line.split(",")[0]
                if dates == date:
                    fng_value=line.split(",")[1]
                    liste.append(fng_value)
print(returns.head(25))
```

OUTPUT:

```
                 BTC-USD
Date                    
2021-06-01  37575.179688

2021-06-02  39208.765625

2021-06-03  36894.406250

2021-06-04  35551.957031

2021-06-05  35862.378906
```

Comment: You are using [naive datetimes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects). Most likely, the data you're filtering has dates that are on the 1st in the data's timezone but on the second in your timezone.

Comment: How can i solve it?

Comment: try `start=dt.datetime.strptime(tarih, '%d-%m-%Y').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)`

Comment: Take the time to read that link and force a timezone when you call `strptime`.

Comment: Could you write it ?

Comment: @JasonM1 it gives a error. Timezone is not defined

Comment: must import it; e.g. `from datetime import datetime, timezone`

Comment: yes i did it but it starts same date which is previous of my filtered

Comment: might have to match timezone for stack exchange; e.g. NYC timezone EST.
```from pytz import timezone
  start = dt.datetime.strptime(tarih, '%d-%m-%Y').replace(tzinfo=timezone('EST'))
  end = dt.datetime.strptime(tarih2, '%d-%m-%Y').replace(tzinfo=timezone('EST'))```

Comment: "TypeError: timezone() argument 1 must be datetime.timedelta, not str" gives error

Comment: write ethe full code pls

Comment: Is that a custom daterange(start,end) function or from a library? Also, have you checked what is in the `dates` after assigning `dt.strftime()`?

Comment: it starts 02/06/2021 after assigning  and also my stars integer is 02/06/2021 but when i get the btc value, it starts 01/06/2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataReader accepts a start parameter as a string, date, or datetime. Apparently, sometimes using start date (e.g. `2021-06-02`) retrieves data starting from the previous day on 2021-06-01. Try to use a datetime with timezone and an hour late in the day to hack the date if it doesn't return what you expect it to.

See if this works:

```python
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime, date

tarih = "02-06-2021"
tarih2 = "05-06-2021"

# start/end can be date, datetime, or string

#start = date(2021, 6, 2)
#end = date(2021, 6, 5)
#start = 'JUN-02-2021'
#end = 'JUN-05-2021'

start = datetime.strptime(tarih, '%d-%m-%Y').replace(hour=23, tzinfo=timezone('EST'))
end = datetime.strptime(tarih2, '%d-%m-%Y').replace(tzinfo=timezone('EST'))

tickers=['BTC-USD']  # Name of asset

for ticker in tickers:
    data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(data)
```

This returns the data from 6/2 to 6/5.

Comment: It gives previous data which is my filtered :(

Comment: updated try with date instance rather than datetime

Comment: still starts on 6/1 ??

Comment: And if just use a formatted date string. Works for me. Somewhere the timezone is getting jacked up.

Comment: Must be an undocumented feature in the web.DataReader and Yahoo reader which works in US timezones.

Comment: here's a hack - try changing default timezone. `os.environ['TZ'] = 'US/Eastern'`

Comment: how can i change it ?

Comment: omg it starts 01/06/2021 why it is like it whyyy?

Comment: weird. Try `start = dt.date(2021, 6, 2)` and comment out the other start = 'JUN...' line.

Comment: nope it starts 01/06/2021 again. When i check the starts integer in my code, it start the 02/06/2021 but when i get the yahoo btc data, it gives a 01/06/2021

Comment: So if you add one to the day; e.g. `start = dt.date(2021, 6, 3)` then you get the ticker data from 6/2 onward ?

Comment: Looks like no easy getting around timezone issue. Some underlying issue in the web.DataReader and Yahoo reader implementation. Workaround is just add plus 1 to day of week in the start date.

Comment: one more try - see update use datetime but force hour=23

Comment: wow  wow wow !! You are amazing. It works. Thanks a lot. Also i only use start = dt.datetime.strptime(tarih, '%d-%m-%Y').replace(hour=23)

Comment: Weird hack. whatever works. I've needed to do timezone hacks before.